# Insert a link in a specific index in quill editor

Tags: quill

I am trying to insert a anchor text at a specific position in the quill editor.

```
 var fullEditor = new Quill('#m_wiki_textarea', {
              modules: {
                'toolbar': { container: '#toolbar' },
                 'image-tooltip': true,
                'link-tooltip': true
              },
              theme: 'snow'
            });
            fullEditor.setHTML(m_wiki_current);
           //added by pavneet
            console.log("added by pavneet");

          $(document).keypress("q",function(e) {
          if(e.ctrlKey)
         {
           var range = fullEditor.getSelection();
           var index = range.start;
                console.log(range);
            console.log(index);
 fullEditor.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(index,'<a class="wiki_link_details" data-l_id="3698">Learn more from this resource</a>');
         }`
```

But i am getting this error , Cannot read property 'dangerouslyPasteHTML' of undefined. But i have defined the editor already.

IS there a way to insert a link in quill editor?

Comment: What version of Quill are you using? Your initialization syntax looks like v0.20.

Comment: @jhchen - Is there a way to add <h2> tags also when you bold a certain text in the editor

Comment: You should take a look at the 0.20 docs then http://quilljs.com/0.20/

Answer (score 9):

Use [updateContents](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#updatecontents)

Example:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow' // or 'bubble'
});

quill.insertText(0, "abc ");

var delta = {
  ops: [
    {retain: 4},
    {insert: "Learn more from this resource", attributes: {link: "http://wikipedia.org"}}
  ]
};
quill.updateContents(delta);
```

```css
#editor-container {
  height: 375px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.6/quill.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="editor-container"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert a div or anchor or parah (basically any element) with a class attribute and a data attribute?

Comment: You can't insert arbitrary HTML. You can use clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(html). Quill will translate your HTML to ops and leave the supported formats. You can follow this guide to add more formats http://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#content-and-formatting

Comment: These guidelines are difficult to understand. can you please share a working example where a class attribute or data attribute is added. If I use a sethtml() function it works, but i need to add the element at a certain position

Comment: Type some text. Select it and click the C button (custom). The span will have a class ql-custom-test. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGRQrx

Comment: This is an example how to format text with ql-custom-test from the API: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORvvXG

Comment: thanks for `['image', 'code-block']` I used it for images and videos

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should insert a text, and then select it and make it a link ([demo](https://codepen.io/splintor/pen/GRWryrM)):

```
function addLink(quill, index, text, url) {
  quill.insertText(index, text, 'user');
  quill.setSelection(index, text.length);
  quill.theme.tooltip.edit('link', url);
  quill.theme.tooltip.save();
}
```